# Why is Outlook Unable to Save a Particular Type of Attachments?

Tags: outlook, attachment

I have a little VBA macro to save attachments in Outlook using the following snippet

```
For Each objAtt In objSourceItem.Attachments
  strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName 
  objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
Next
```

This works for all types of attachments except for ChemDraw attachments. I get an error saying that "Outlook cannot perform this action on this type of attachment"
I am not sure if this specific to ChemDraw, but I maybe it has to do with file extension and Outlook not recognizing the file format. Anyway, this http://www.cambridgesoft.com/services/documentation/sdk/chemdraw/cdx/General.htm has info on ChemDraw type files. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an embedded OLE object in an RTF message, Outlook will not be able to extract the actual file data from the attachment (which is an OLE storage blob - IStorage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it is an embedded OLE object, but Outlook is able to save other types of embedded object. Actually I am not really interested in "saving" the attachments but more interesting in copying it to another email. I know that for regular attachments this is not possible to simply copy the attachment from one email to the other, because you will need to save it first and then upload it, but I should be able to copy and paste embedded OLE objects? If so, what would be the VBA code for a conditional statement that checks whether an attachment is an embedded OLE objecy? Thanks!

Comment: Check the Attachment.Type property (olEmbeddedItem = 5)

Comment: Just an FYI, Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) can extract file data from the embedded OLE attachments - see RDOAttachment.SaveAsFile (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm)