# Outlook cannot perform this action on this type of attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to save attachments from an email. I get the error message

> Outlook cannot perform this action on this type of attachment

Using `Debug.Print outAttachment`, it is trying to extract a Picture (Device Independent Bitmap).
I only need the Excel and pdf extracted, but I don't mind extracting the picture if it means the code works.

```vb
Public Sub Extract_Attachments_From_Outlook_Msg_Files()
    
    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outEmail As Object
    Dim outAttachment As Object
    Dim msgFiles As String, sourceFolder As String, saveInFolder As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           
    msgFiles = Sheets("Instructions").Range("H1") & Sheets("Instructions").Range("H2") & ".msg" 'folder location and filespec of .msg files"
    Debug.Print msgFiles
    saveInFolder = Sheets("Instructions").Range("H1")         'folder where extracted attachments are saved
    Debug.Print saveInFolder
        
    If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"
        sourceFolder = Left(msgFiles, InStrRev(msgFiles, "\"))
        Debug.Print sourceFolder
        On Error Resume Next
        Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If outApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not open"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        fileName = Dir(msgFiles)
        While fileName <> vbNullString
        
        Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(sourceFolder & fileName)
            
        For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
            outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
        Next
        
        fileName = Dir
            
    Wend
        
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of attachment is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706422/why-is-outlook-unable-to-save-a-particular-type-of-attachments

Comment: pdf and excel file!

Comment: Both on the same message?

Comment: Maybe check here: https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/savingdeleting-all-attachments-with-one-click/ and search for the `IsHiddenAttachment` function.  I've not seen this, but apparently some attachments are "hidden" and need to be skipped when exporting.

Comment: ACtually when running through the code and using `Debug.Print outAttachment` , it seems like it is trying to extract a Picture (Device Independent Bitmap) , anyone know how to deal with this? I only need the excel and pdf extracted.

Comment: Hi - did you try checking the file extension of the `outAttachment.fileName`? You could use the `GetExtensionName` method in the `FileSystemObject` class to determine the extension.

Comment: Well the person sending the email sent a photo in it aswell, I want to bypass the photo.  So I would only want to include .xlsx and .pdf

Comment: That seems like the problem addressed in the link I posted.

Comment: I see. I need help incorporating the `If isHiddenAttachment` piece in my code.

Comment: How about using error handling and if that particular error is raised then Resume Next?

Comment: Yes I can try that. I ended up just removing this from my code and finding another way to do it. But I would interested in fixing for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an RTF-formatted message with embedded OLE objects, right?
Outlook Object Model does not allow to do much with attachments of that type (`Attachment.Type == olOLE`).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), its [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` method is smart  enough to extract BMP, EMF, PDF, Excel, etc. file data from the storage. Something like the following (off the top of my head) should do the job:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set outEmail= Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(sourceFolder & fileName)
  For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
      outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
  Next
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I'm getting `ActiveX component can't create object` on the Set Session line.

Comment: Did you download and install Redemption?

Comment: My company wont allow it.

Comment: There is not much you can do then. You can try to use Extended MAPI to extract the attachment data, but that requires C++ or Delphi. Note that you don';t need admin rights to install Redemption - you can copy the dll to any folder and register it using regsvr32.exe; it will be happy to install itself in HKCU.

Answer (score 0):

I used:
If att.Type <> olOLE Then

to just skip that object so that I could continue to extract all other attachments.